# How to solve this problem? Let $x(t) = t^2 + 3t, y(t) = (t^3)/3$, be a parametric curve. Find the points where the tangents

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $x(t) = t^2 + 3t, y(t) = (t^3)/3$, be a parametric curve. Find the points where the tangents
have slope 1.

point(−2,−1/3) is easy to find
but how to find (18,9)

Comment: Solve $\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)} = 1$. Simple as that

Answer (score 1):

You wish to solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$ Then you can use chain rule: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)}=\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}=1$$

Then solve this:

$$\frac{t^2}{2t+3}=1\implies t^2-2t-3=0$$
Solve this quadratic to obtain 2 values of $t$, which will give you the two solutions you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know where $\frac{t^2}{2t+3}=1$ so the solutions to $t^2-2t-3=(t+1)(t-3)=0$ are $t=-1$ and $t=3$.